# ANOVA Assumptions on Big data

Tags: r, anova, dataset, assumptions, large-data

I wanted to know if one would require to check for the violation of ANOVA Assumptions before running an ANOVA model on a Big Dataset (size of the big dataset is 57 million rows)?

Thanks!

Comment: What confidence level $\alpha$ are you going to choose? With a sample size of 57 million (assuming a simple design) your test is going to be extremely sensitive to even a tiny difference among the means. Without considering what effect size you care about you may just be computing the answer to a foregone conclusion.